# How can I display custom content in vue-good-table within my view-side component?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-good-table

I'm new to VueJS and decided to use a library called Vue-good-table (doc here : https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/ ) to display a datatable in my laravel project instead of the usual Yajra datatables which uses jQuery. I have been able to display my data from backend but now I'm struggling to include an edit button in a custom "actions" column. I've tried many ways but none has been successful. I need a way to redirect to the edit page on button's click so my guess is I need to handle the custom column template in my php view file. Here's the code to make it more explicit :

Php controller :

```
public function index() {
    $users = json_encode(User::latest()->get());
    $userColumns = json_encode([
            [
                'label' => 'ID',
                'field' => 'id'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'name',
                'field' => 'name'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Email',
                'field' => 'email'
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Action',
                'field' => 'actions'
            ]
    ]);

    return view('admin.users.index', compact('users', 'userColumns'));
}
```

Vue component :

```
<template>
<div>
    <vue-good-table
        :columns="columns"
        :rows="rows"
        compactMode
    >
        <slot></slot>
    </vue-good-table>

</div>
</template>

<script>
   import { VueGoodTable } from 'vue-good-table';

   export default {
     props: ['rows', 'columns'],
     components : { VueGoodTable },
   }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The app.js file :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Datatables from './components/datatables';



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    components : {
        'bdfr-datatables' : Datatables,
    },
}
```

View php file :

```
@section('content')
    <bdfr-datatables :rows="{{ $users }}" :columns="{{ $userColumns }}">
        <!-- wishing to display this part -->
        <template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">
            <span v-if="props.column.field === 'actions'">
                <a href="#">Edit</a>
            </span>
            <span v-else>
                @{{props.formattedRow[props.column.field]}}
            </span>
         </template>
    </bdfr-datatables>
@endsection
```

What am I missing to make it work ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm struggling to include an edit button in a custom "actions" column. I've tried many ways but none has been successful. I need a way to redirect to the edit page on button's click

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to display a link that redirect's to the user edition's form, *via* an url that would look like `/user/1/edit`.

- First, check what Laravels returns

You may want to go with `dd(User::latest()->get());` for that. By default, you should get the id alongside other informations, unless you explicitly `$guarded` them.

- Then, adapt your solution with vue-good-table's template system

If you check [this link](https://xaksis.github.io/vue-good-table/guide/advanced/#customizations), it shows you an example of a table that seems to display the "age" column with a specific style, and the rest by default. What's interesting here is that it shows you that each of your users can be reached *via* `props.row`.

So what you'd need to do is something like follows:

```html
  <template slot="table-row" slot-scope="props">
    <span v-if="props.column.field == 'actions'">
      <a :href="`/user/${props.row.id}/edit`">Edit</a>
    </span>
    <span v-else>
      {{props.formattedRow[props.column.field]}}
    </span>
  </template>
</vue-good-table>
```